# Repeating a div based on user input (JavaScript solution preferred)

Tags: javascript, html

Looking for the simplest implementation of the following problem:

I have a user input number field like:

```
<input type="number" id="numInput" name="numInput" value="1" onchange="myFunc()">

<div id="demo">*** TEST ***</div>
```

I want to replicate the #demo div based on the #numInput value entered by the user, e.g. if the user enters '5', there would be five #demo divs displayed on the page. At the moment, I'm using the following function:

```
function myFunc() {
  var newArray = [];
  var numInput = document.getElementById('numInput').value;
  var x = document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML;

  for(var i=0; i<numInput; i++) {
    newArray.push(x);
  }

  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = newArray;
}
```

but this is adding to the existing array rather than outputting the exact number of divs based on user input. Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There should not be multiple same id values.

```js
function myFunc() {
  let numInput = document.getElementById("numInput");
  while (numInput.nextSibling) {
    numInput.nextSibling.remove();
  }
  
  let numInputval = document.getElementById('numInput').value;
  for(var i=numInputval; i>0; i--) {
    var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.setAttribute('id', 'demo' + i);
    newDiv.innerHTML = '*** TEST ***';
    numInput.parentNode.insertBefore(newDiv, numInput.nextSibling);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="numInput" name="numInput" onchange="myFunc()">
```

**+Edit**
You can also manipulate `<form>` with javascript.

```js
function myFunc() {
  let numInput = document.getElementById("numInput");
  while (numInput.nextSibling) {
    numInput.nextSibling.remove();
  }
  
  let numInputval = document.getElementById('numInput').value;
  for(var i=numInputval; i>0; i--) {
    var newInput = document.createElement('input');
    newInput.setAttribute('id', 'demoInput' + i);
    newInput.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    newInput.setAttribute('name', 'demoInputName' + i);
    newInput.setAttribute('onchange', 'myFormChangeListener(this)');
    numInput.parentNode.insertBefore(newInput, numInput.nextSibling);
    numInput.parentNode.insertBefore(document.createElement('br'), numInput.nextSibling);
  }
}

function myFormChangeListener(element) {
  console.log(element);
  console.log(element.value);
  myForm.action = 'http://the.url/';
  myForm.method = 'post';
  console.log(myForm);
  //myForm.submit;
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="number" id="numInput" name="numInput" onchange="myFunc()">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. Extending on the above example, assuming the inputs are part of a form submission, any advice on how I can capture these inputs as a PHP POST request? I can record the POST request when there is only input field, but when the number of input fields dynamically change based on user input, I'm not sure how to capture the resulting inputs.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @moin205 would you take a look at the edited content?

Comment: Thanks! I was able to implement the solution in PHP (JS not needed) in regard to my comment above.